# How to hide cell separator in a static cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have custom static cells in a `UITableView`, and I want to remove the cell separator in **some specified cell**. But how can I programmatically do this in static cells?

My device :iphone 5 iOS 7
IOS simulator:iphone 4s-iphone 6p , all iOS 8.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to set the table's separatorStyle to UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone and manually adding/drawing a line (perhaps in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) when you want it.

Use like this,

```
...
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    // Drawing our own separatorLine here because I need to turn it off for the
    // last row. I can only do that on the tableView and on on specific cells.
    // The y position below has to be 1 less than the cell height to keep it from
    // disappearing when the tableView is scrolled.
    UIImageView *separatorLine = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, cell.frame.size.height - 1.0f, cell.frame.size.width, 1.0f)];
    separatorLine.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"grayDot"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:1 topCapHeight:0];
    separatorLine.tag = 4;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:separatorLine];

    [separatorLine release];
}

// Setup default cell setttings.
...
UIImageView *separatorLine = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
separatorLine.hidden = NO;
...
// In the cell I want to hide the line, I just hide it.
seperatorLine.hidden = YES;
```

Set in ViewDidload

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just use this code in** - `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method,

```
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, cell.bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.f);
```

**If you want for a specific cell:-**

```
if(indexpath.row==1) //desired row number on which you don't want separator
{
 cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, cell.bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.f);
}
```

Comment: I write the code ,but it doesn't work..Actually I have attempt to do the job using the separatorInset, but never work.... UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, cell.bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.f);

Comment: Can i write the code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method of a static cells? If yes, how can I get the cell?

Comment: what do you mean 'comments section'? actually i want to know what I use cell.separatorInset, at where I declare the cell?Thanks for you help...

Comment: -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //it is a statics table view
    UITableViewCell *cell=[super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(indexPath.section==0)
        cell.separatorInset=UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 10000.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    return cell;
}

Answer (score 0):

Since separator style is a property of the table, and not the cell, the easiest way is going to be to hide all of the separators:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

and then explicitly draw a separator in the cells that need one.  Typically the easiest way to do that is to add a one-pixel high subview at the bottom (or top) of the cell and set it's background color to black.

Answer (score 0):

Make link from your static cell to UITableViewController and:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    yourStaticCell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, yourStaticCell.bounds.size.width, 0.f, 0.f);
}
```